# swift extracting bytes from struct Data

Tags: ios, swift3

data is arriving in the form of `struct Data` size `count == 5` the last 3 bytes contain an ID that needs to be extracted.

The following code works, however I am sure it could be greatly improved (as you can tell I am new to swift!):

```
var data:[UInt8] = [ 0xff, 0xff, 0x01, 0x02 ,0x03 ]
var txData = Data(bytes: data)
print(txData.count)
let byte00 = txData.subdata(in: 2..<3 ).withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt8 in
    return ptr.pointee
}
let byte01 = txData.subdata(in: 3..<4 ).withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt8 in
    return ptr.pointee
}
let byte02 = txData.subdata(in: 4..<5 ).withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt8 in
    return ptr.pointee
}

let rxData = (UInt(byte00) << 16) + (UInt(byte01) << 8) + UInt(byte02)
print( String(rxData, radix:16) )
```

Any tutorial recommendations covering this area of swift would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Unsafe Swift: Using Pointers And Interacting With C](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148569/unsafe-swift?utm_source=raywenderlich.com+Weekly&utm_campaign=0863916fc0-raywenderlich_com_Weekly11_29_2016&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_83b6edc87f-0863916fc0-414818977)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
var data:[UInt8] = [ 0xff, 0xff, 0x01, 0x02 ,0x03 ]
var txData = Data(bytes: data)
print(txData.count)
let byte00 = txData[2]
let byte01 = txData[3]
let byte02 = txData[4]

let rxData = (UInt(byte00) << 16) + (UInt(byte01) << 8) + UInt(byte02)
print( String(rxData, radix:16) ) //->10203
```

In Swift 3, `Data` can be treated as a Collection of `UInt8`, you can subscript to `Data` directly when getting each byte as `UInt8`.

And as 3 byte is not a good number for the current CPUs, the code above cannot be much shorter.